# The method HtmlDecode has invalid arguments?

Tags: .net

Hi i am using RichEditor . This Editor saves span and style in the table . 
So, I am using following method to avoid this: `HtmlDecode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageDesc"))`

But its giving error like:

> HtmlCode Has some invalid arguments

How can  i solve this .The c# code is:

```
public string HtmlDecode(string strValue)
    {
        string functionReturnValue = null;
        try
        {
            functionReturnValue = Server.HtmlDecode(strValue);

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
           // ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
        }
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could strValue be Null? Try adding a null test. If it's null, replace with an empty string.